# dd + gz = Even Worse /// Mount Valid Partition of Whole-Disk dd Image

Tags: linux, backup, dd, gzip

I've got a 250G backup of a whole disk via `dd`, which was then piped to `gz`, thanks to the advice of one of my -genius- friends.

Looks like the EFI boot partition was corrupted (pretty sure it's an Apple-style GUID partition map starting with an EFI partition), which prevents me from trying to mount it with anything (like `kvm` or via `loopfs`)

I'm not entirely sure how to unwrap its `gzip` container, since *of course* no zip-related programs can read through the image (like `zcat` / `gzip` / `gunzip`).

**TO BE CLEAR** it's not a `.tar.gz`, rather it's a `dd` image with a straight `.gz`.

I know that inside this blob of data exists a perfectly valid partition with data I'd like to recover.

So if there's anything I can do to further my scavenger hunt, please let me know: many thanks in advance :)

Comment: `I'm not entirely sure how to unwrap its gzip container, since of course no zip-related programs can read through the image (like zcat / gzip / gunzip).` Ugh, what?

Comment: Once decompressed with `gunzip` or `gzip -d`, use `losetup` with `-P` to set up a loop device, then you can mount the filesystem on any of the partitions.

Comment: @TomYan Please make that an answer. Just add that "if gunzip doesn't work, it's corrupted" and it's a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to decompress the file using `gunzip` or cat it with `zcat`. If you can't, then the file is corrupted.

You can try to dig deeper using the `file` command or even `binwalk`. Maybe the file is wrapped one more time into something and you just don't remember doing it.